# How to read a column value from an array

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have below VB6 code where in VB6 code there are two parameters being passed to read a column value from an array of collection. How to migrated this code to Vb.Net. Even I below  I mentioned wizard generated VB.Net code.

```
Private m_colBookmarks As Collection
Private Const COL_ERR_BKMARK_COMP_TITLE = 2
Private Property Get BookmarkCompTitle(ByVal strBookmarkNum As String) As String          
    BookmarkCompTitle = m_colBookmarks(strBookmarkNum)(COL_ERR_BKMARK_COMP_TITLE)
End Property
```

here is the vb.net code.

```
 Private ReadOnly Property BookmarkCompTitle(ByVal strBookmarkNum As String) As String
    Get          

        BookmarkCompTitle = m_colBookmarks.Item(strBookmarkNum)(COL_ERR_BKMARK_COMP_TITLE)
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: What went wrong when you tried?

Comment: craig, when I did option strict on i got "Option Strict On disallows late binding". this is the Vb.Net code..  Private ReadOnly Property BookmarkCompID(ByVal strBookmarkNum As String) As String
        Get
            BookmarkCompID = m_colBookmarks.Item(strBookmarkNum)(COL_ERR_BKMARK_COMP_ID)
        End Get
    End Property

Comment: Yes, and you were given some good suggestions for addressing this when you asked the same question yesterday.  (You even appear to have marked one of them as an accepted answer to the question.)

Comment: Hi Craig, that is different and this one is different. If you see the last one will accepts text as collection member but this one is not.

Comment: In this case, I think you need to cast the result of `m_colBookmarks(strBookmarkNum)` to (whatever its type actually is).  The underlying problem is the same, the difference is likely to be which thing you need to add a type conversion for.  e.g. `BookmarkCompTitle = CType(m_colBookmarks(strBookmarkNum), BookmarkRow)(COL_ERR_BKMARK_COMP_TITLE)`

Comment: Can you put the VB.NET code into your question as well?

Comment: @djv.. i have edited original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class Class1
    Private m_colBookmarks As Collection(Of String())
    Private Const COL_ERR_BKMARK_COMP_TITLE = 2

    ' here Is the vb.net code.
    Private ReadOnly Property BookmarkCompTitle(ByVal strBookmarkNum As String) As String
        Get
            Dim bookmarkNum As Integer

            If Not Int32.TryParse(strBookmarkNum, bookmarkNum) OrElse bookmarkNum < 0 Then                    
                Throw New ArgumentException("strBookmarkNum must be a positive integer.")
            End If

            BookmarkCompTitle = m_colBookmarks.Item(bookmarkNum)(COL_ERR_BKMARK_COMP_TITLE)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Just one question.. how would you address below code m_colBookmarks.Add(astrBookmark, astrBookmark(COL_ERR_BKMARK_NUM))

Comment: What's the value of COL_ERR_BKMARK_NUM? Are you trying to add a new element?